# Fabric.js Sticky Note type text wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fabricjs

I am trying to make a sticky note type utility with the fabric canvas. It will help to be used as annotators.

I want the text to wrap by itself at the given rectangle's width.

Can someone update my fiddle work??

Suggestions are appreciated. Regards...

The following is the link to a part of my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U7E9q/5/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas');

canvas.hoverCursor = 'pointer';

var text = new fabric.IText("Enter Text Here ",{
      fontSize: 20,
      top: 100,
      left: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#faa',
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      selectable: true
});
//alert(text.text);
  var rect   = new fabric.Rect({
    text_field: text,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    fill: '#faa',
    rx: 10,
    ry: 10,
    top: 100,
    left: 100
  });

  canvas.add(rect);
  canvas.add(text);

canvas.on('object:moving', function (event){
   canvas.renderAll(); 
});

createListenersKeyboard();

function createListenersKeyboard() {
    document.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;
    //document.onkeyup = onKeyUpHandler;
}

function onKeyDownHandler(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var key;
    if(window.event){
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else{
        key = event.keyCode;
    }

    switch(key){
        //////////////
        // Shortcuts
        //////////////
        // Copy (Ctrl+C)
        case 67: // Ctrl+C
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    copy();
                }
            }
            break;
        // Delete (Ctrl+D)
        case 127: // Ctrl+D
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.deleteKey){
                    delet();
                }
            }
            break;            
        // Paste (Ctrl+V)
        case 86: // Ctrl+V
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    paste();
                }
            }
            break;            
        default:
            // TODO
            break;
    }
}


function ableToShortcut(){
    /*
    TODO check all cases for this

    if($("textarea").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    if($(":text").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    */
    return true;
}

function copy(){
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        for(var i in canvas.getActiveGroup().objects){
            var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveGroup().objects[i]);
            object.set("top", object.top+5);
            object.set("left", object.left+5);
            copiedObjects[i] = object;
        }                    
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
        object.set("top", object.top+5);
        object.set("left", object.left+5);
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
    }
}

function paste(){
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
            canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
        }                    
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
        canvas.add(copiedObject);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();    
}

function delet(){
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        canvas.remove(activeObject);
        console.log('after remove getActiveObject(): ', canvas.getActiveObject(), activeObject === canvas.getActiveObject());
        canvas.renderAll();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you manage the sticky note as a grouped rect and text you can improve the same behavior. When you need to edit the text inside the group, you just ungroup and clone the elements, append the cloned elements to the canvas and set text as editable.

You need to handle an event like double click to handle this behavior and then handle the mousedown or other interactivity with canvas to regroup them.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/4HE3U/1/
Above is one fiddle that can satisfy you

Basically i have made one group of Text and Rectangle and i have added it to canvas. There is only one change you need to make is that you can take one textbox to get current sticky note text content as we can not edit text of i-text online once we are adding it any group. Currently there is no way for IText to handle the events as they are not handed down to it if it's contained in a group. I think this is also the prefered way to handle that as it would confuse the user - what if he starts to edit multiple texts. This might end up in a mess. Maybe you can rework your script a little to workaround this problems.

I have added Text and Rectangle

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric-canvas');

canvas.hoverCursor = 'pointer';

var text = new fabric.IText("Enter Text Here ",{
      fontSize: 20,
      top: 100,
      left: 100,
      backgroundColor: '#faa',
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      selectable: true
});
//alert(text.text);
  var rect   = new fabric.Rect({
    text_field: text,
    width: 200,
    height: 50,
    fill: '#faa',
    rx: 10,
    ry: 10,
    top: 100,
    left: 100
  });


var group = new fabric.Group([ rect, text ], {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  lockScalingX: true,
  lockScalingY: true,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
  transparentCorners: false,
  cornerSize: 7
});

  canvas.add(group);
  //canvas.add(text);

canvas.on('object:moving', function (event){
   canvas.renderAll(); 
});

createListenersKeyboard();

function createListenersKeyboard() {
    document.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;
    //document.onkeyup = onKeyUpHandler;
}

function onKeyDownHandler(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    
    var key;
    if(window.event){
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else{
        key = event.keyCode;
    }
    
    switch(key){
        //////////////
        // Shortcuts
        //////////////
        // Copy (Ctrl+C)
        case 67: // Ctrl+C
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    copy();
                }
            }
            break;
        // Delete (Ctrl+D)
        case 127: // Ctrl+D
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.deleteKey){
                    delet();
                }
            }
            break;            
        // Paste (Ctrl+V)
        case 86: // Ctrl+V
            if(ableToShortcut()){
                if(event.ctrlKey){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    paste();
                }
            }
            break;            
        default:
            // TODO
            break;
    }
}


function ableToShortcut(){
    /*
    TODO check all cases for this
    
    if($("textarea").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    if($(":text").is(":focus")){
        return false;
    }
    */
    return true;
}

function copy(){
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()){
        for(var i in canvas.getActiveGroup().objects){
            var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveGroup().objects[i]);
            object.set("top", object.top+5);
            object.set("left", object.left+5);
            copiedObjects[i] = object;
        }                    
    }
    else if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
        var object = fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
        object.set("top", object.top+5);
        object.set("left", object.left+5);
        copiedObject = object;
        copiedObjects = new Array();
    }
}

function paste(){
    if(copiedObjects.length > 0){
        for(var i in copiedObjects){
            canvas.add(copiedObjects[i]);
        }                    
    }
    else if(copiedObject){
        canvas.add(copiedObject);
    }
    canvas.renderAll();    
}

function delet(){
        var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
        canvas.remove(activeObject);
        console.log('after remove getActiveObject(): ', canvas.getActiveObject(), activeObject === canvas.getActiveObject());
        canvas.renderAll();    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="fabric-canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: no, this is not gonna work. I need the two objects binded to each other and yet have the editable functionality. However by the time you answered I deep dived into fabric & realised this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Sticky note functionality. Text wrap working and font size changes w.r.t sticky note width and height. Editing mode activates on double click.

```js
export const createStickyNotes = (canvas, options) => {
  fabric.StickyNote = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    type: "StickyNote",
    initialize: function (options) {
      this.set(options);
      var height = this.height;
      var width = this.width;

      this.rectObj = new fabric.Rect({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fill: this.rectObj?.fill ?? "rgba(251,201,112,1)",
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        objectCaching: false,
        stateProperties: ["fill"],
      });
      this.textObj = new fabric.Textbox(this.textObj?.text ?? "Notes", {
        originX: "center",
        originY: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
        width: 100,
        hasControls: false,
        fontSize: this.textObj?.fontSize ?? 30,
        lineHeight: 1,
        stateProperties: ["text", "fontSize"],
        scaleX: this.textObj?.scaleX ?? 1,
        scaleY: this.textObj?.scaleY ?? 1,
        objectCaching: false,
        breakWords: true,
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
      });

      this._objects = [this.rectObj, this.textObj];
      //   this custom _set function will set custom properties value to object when it will load from json.
      // at that time loadFromJson function will call this initialize function.
      // this._setCustomProperties(this.options);
      canvas.renderAll();

      //evenet will fire if the object is double clicked by mouse
      this.on("mousedblclick", (e) => {
        var pasteFlag = false;
        var scaling = e.target.getScaledWidth() / 100;
        var textForEditing;
        canvas.bringToFront(e.target);
        e.target.selectable = false;
        const [rectObj, textObj] = this.getObjects();
        textObj.clone(function (clonedObj) {
          clonedObj.set({
            left: e.target.left,
            top: e.target.top,
            lockMovementY: true,
            lockMovementX: true,
            hasBorders: false,
            scaleX: scaling,
            scaleY: scaling,
            breakWords: true,
            width: textObj.width,
            stateProperties: [],
          });
          textForEditing = clonedObj;
        });

        this.remove(textObj);
        canvas.add(textForEditing);
        canvas.setActiveObject(textForEditing);

        textForEditing.enterEditing();
        textForEditing.selectAll();

        textForEditing.paste = (function (paste) {
          return function (e) {
            disableScrolling();
            pasteFlag = true;
          };
        })(textForEditing.paste);

        textForEditing.on("changed", function (e) {
          var fontSize = textForEditing.fontSize;
          var charCount = Math.max(textForEditing._text.length, 1);
          var charWR =
            (textForEditing.textLines.length * width) / (charCount * fontSize);

          if (textForEditing.height < height - 15) {
            fontSize = Math.min(
              Math.sqrt(
                ((height - 10 - fontSize) / 1.16) *
                  (width / (charCount * charWR))
              ),
              30
            );
          }
          if (textForEditing.height > height - 15) {
            fontSize = Math.sqrt(
              ((height - 10) / 1.16) * (width / (charCount * charWR))
            );
          }
          if (pasteFlag) {
            pasteFlag = false;
            while (
              textForEditing.height > height - 15 &&
              textForEditing.fontSize > 0
            ) {
              fontSize = textForEditing.fontSize -= 0.2;
              canvas.renderAll();
            }
          }
          textForEditing.fontSize = fontSize;
        });

        textForEditing.on("editing:exited", () => {
          enableScrolling();
          canvas.setActiveObject(textObj);
          textObj.set({
            text: textForEditing.text,
            fontSize: textForEditing.fontSize,
            visible: true,
          });
          this.add(textObj);
          this.selectable = true;
          canvas.remove(textForEditing);
          canvas.discardActiveObject();
        });
      });

      function disableScrolling() {
        var x = window.scrollX;
        var y = window.scrollY;
        window.onscroll = function () {
          window.scrollTo(x, y);
        };
      }

      var _wrapLine = function (_line, lineIndex, desiredWidth, reservedSpace) {
        var lineWidth = 0,
          splitByGrapheme = this.splitByGrapheme,
          graphemeLines = [],
          line = [],
          // spaces in different languges?
          words = splitByGrapheme
            ? fabric.util.string.graphemeSplit(_line)
            : _line.split(this._wordJoiners),
          word = "",
          offset = 0,
          infix = splitByGrapheme ? "" : " ",
          wordWidth = 0,
          infixWidth = 0,
          largestWordWidth = 0,
          lineJustStarted = true,
          additionalSpace = splitByGrapheme ? 0 : this._getWidthOfCharSpacing();

        reservedSpace = reservedSpace || 0;
        desiredWidth -= reservedSpace;
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          // i would avoid resplitting the graphemes
          word = fabric.util.string.graphemeSplit(words[i]);
          wordWidth = this._measureWord(word, lineIndex, offset);
          offset += word.length;

          // Break the line if a word is wider than the set width
          if (this.breakWords && wordWidth >= desiredWidth) {
            if (!lineJustStarted) {
              graphemeLines.push(line);
              line = [];
              lineWidth = 0;
              lineJustStarted = true;
            }
            this.fontSize *= desiredWidth / (wordWidth + 1);
            // Loop through each character in word
            for (var w = 0; w < word.length; w++) {
              var letter = word[w];
              var letterWidth =
                (this.getMeasuringContext().measureText(letter).width *
                  this.fontSize) /
                this.CACHE_FONT_SIZE;
              line.push(letter);
              lineWidth += letterWidth;
            }
            word = [];
          } else {
            lineWidth += infixWidth + wordWidth - additionalSpace;
          }

          if (lineWidth >= desiredWidth && !lineJustStarted) {
            graphemeLines.push(line);
            line = [];
            lineWidth = wordWidth;
            lineJustStarted = true;
          } else {
            lineWidth += additionalSpace;
          }

          if (!lineJustStarted) {
            line.push(infix);
          }
          line = line.concat(word);

          infixWidth = this._measureWord([infix], lineIndex, offset);
          offset++;
          lineJustStarted = false;
          // keep track of largest word
          if (wordWidth > largestWordWidth && !this.breakWords) {
            largestWordWidth = wordWidth;
          }
        }

        i && graphemeLines.push(line);

        if (largestWordWidth + reservedSpace > this.dynamicMinWidth) {
          this.dynamicMinWidth =
            largestWordWidth - additionalSpace + reservedSpace;
        }

        return graphemeLines;
      };

      fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Textbox.prototype, {
        _wrapLine: _wrapLine,
      });

      function enableScrolling() {
        window.onscroll = function () {};
      }
    },

    toObject: function (propertiesToInclude) {
      // This function is used for serialize this object. (used for create json)
      // not inlclude this.textObj and this.rectObj into json because when object will load from json, init fucntion of this class is called and it will assign this two object textObj and rectObj again.
      var obj = this.callSuper(
        "toObject",
        [
          "objectCaching",
          "textObj",
          "rectObj",
          // ... property list that you want to add into json when this object is convert into json using toJSON() function. (serialize)
        ].concat(propertiesToInclude)
      );
      // delete objects array from json because then object load from json, Init function will call. which will automatically re-assign object and assign _object array.
      delete obj.objects;
      return obj;
    },
  });

  fabric.StickyNote.async = true;
  fabric.StickyNote.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    // This function is used for deserialize json and convert object json into button object again. (called when we call loadFromJson() fucntion on canvas)
    return fabric.Object._fromObject("StickyNote", object, callback);
  };

  return new fabric.StickyNote(options);
};
```

```js
//How to use 


 var options = {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",
    };
    var notes = StickyNotes(canvas, options);
    canvas.add(notes);
```